# Using one class with context for everything

Tags: android, android-context

I'm using a class which can return different things that are obtained with help of a context. For example, if I need an alarmmanager I can use a method of this class which will return me one. However, this class is static and uses base context of an application which it takes from context of an activity during first initialization of the class. Now I want to know if my app will be removed from RAM then this class won't be operable anymore, will it?

The case of which I'm thinking of is: user set an alarm at 7:00am the night before; after that my application was shut down; then, at 7:00am alarm will work but when my application will try to use this class it will just crush, am I correct?

```
public class ServicesManager {

    private static Application myApp;
    private static ServicesManager ourInstance;

    public static ServicesManager getInstance() {
        if(ourInstance == null){
            ourInstance = new ServicesManager(myApp);
        }
        return ourInstance;
    }

    public ServicesManager(Application application) {
        myApp = application;
    }

    public Context getContext(){
        return myApp.getBaseContext();
    }

    public AlarmManager getAlarmServiceManager(){
        return (AlarmManager) myApp.getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    }

}
```

Comment: use a subclass of application

Comment: static context means memory leaks. Your idea is good, but i suggest adding context as method parameter instead of member variable. Or use data injection.